# What does "render" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does "render" mean in this sentense?

> Most programs are tedious to write in the
>   bare language, whereas just about any task can be **rendered** simple by the use of good libraries.

Comment: What's the down vote for?

Comment: I believe because it appears to be a basic meaning question, without specifying the ambiguity. I think it's a reasonable question - especially in the context of computer science, I can see how a English is a second language speaker could be confused.

Comment: @dwjohnston Thanks, you are right, I did search the word before ask question, it has so many different meanings, that's why I ask here. I think the people who down vote might also don't know the answer ...

Comment: You need only to render + adjective and that is no. 1 in Oald's entry of to render. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/render?q=render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means 'made' in this context.

> Most programs are tedious to write in the bare language, whereas just about any task can be ***made*** simple by the use of good libraries.

‌

> **[render](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/render)** *verb*
>
> 1. **to cause to be or become; make: *to render someone helpless.***
> 2. to do; perform: *to render a service.*
> 3. to furnish; provide: *to render aid.*
> 4. to exhibit or show (obedience, attention, etc.).
> 5. to present for consideration, approval, payment, action, etc., as an account.
> 6. to return; to make (a payment in money, kind, or service) as by a tenant to a superior: *knights rendering military service to the lord.*
> 7. to pay as due (a tax, tribute, etc.).

dictionary.reference.com